# USB005 Infineon dongle schematic

Tags: i2c

Does anyone have a schematic for the usb005 Infineon dongle?
We need to program exactly Infineon IC's, and I would like to understand is there any special features, or we could use any similar dongle or MCU.
[image]

Comment: Questions seeking off-site resources are off topic; check with infineon, try a *discussion forum* (which this is not) or examine the technical literature - it seems unlikely that this is the only way to program a part which would often end up in an embedded system with its own I2C host.

Comment: "`Does anyone have a schematic for the usb005 Infineon dongle?`" Likely no one on this website will. Contact Infineon for details but they won't give you any schematics."`I would like to understand is there any special features`" What do you mean by "special features"? There probably won't be anything groundbreaking if that's what you're talking about. "`or we could use any similar dongle or MCU`" That depends on the dongle and chip... Again, talk with Infineon.

Comment: @KingDuken their *software* is probably expecting something specific in terms of a USB-I2C interface; but hopefully that is not the only option; eg, typically with something like this (if the manufacture has any actual engineers on staff) you can export a block of configuration data to use in your own embedded controller's program.

Comment: @Chris Agreed. I have some experience with some Dediprog stuff. They had a large library of expected ROM chips to select from to burn a binary onto :)